# Transmission time of a TCP socket

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming

I am wondering whether the transmission time of a TCP socket configurable. I am sending a TCP packet with payload of size 19 bytes and the transmission time seems to be 1 sec approx. Can this be brought down or does one have to just accept whatever it is?

Comment: Do you expect a magic setting somewhere to make the Internet faster or something? :-)

Comment: One second seems inordinately long for transmitting a pacet of any size. However, you have little control over it since it's determined by routing protocols and link speeds. If this is a local transmission talk to your network people and ask them to investigate

Comment: Yeah. It is an internal network of just 4 systems which are directly connected without any switch. I am looking for a way to increase the data transmission speed. Let me check with my administrator.

Comment: Also a peace of your code would give us more information, how you write and read. It's seems to long for just 19bytes. In this 1 sec. do you count the connections (connect) as well?

Comment: @Mat - Actually, in this case, yes, there probably is such a magic setting, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

How exactly do you calculate this time? I hope you're not comparing the time of two different computers, since their clocks are probably not identical.

However, having said this, you're probably suffering from the Nagle algorithm where the connection waits to transmit data to see if there's more to batch together. You can turn this off by setting the Tcp options.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.nodelay.aspx

Comment: +1 [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm) deliberately penalizes small-data senders in hopes of improving overall network efficiency.

Comment: The Nagle algorithm doesn't wait a whole second.

Comment: @EJP - No, but it typically does wait 500ms, which is half a second.  And that's why asked how they were measuring this.  They may also be measuring the round trip time (may take 500ms coming back) which would equal a full second.